# Why does std::distance print out a `-`?

Tags: c++, distance

I wrote the following program to print out the occurrence of an alphabet starting with `a=0`, `b=1` and so on.  Could someone please point out why using std::distance is printing out a blank `-` and how I could get rid of it?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;

    int n=str.size();
    std::vector<char> table(26);
    table = {
        'a',    'b',    'c',    'd',    'e',    'f',    'g',    'h',    'i',    'j',    'k',    'l',    'm',    'n',    'o',    'p',    'q',    'r',    's',    't',    'u',    'v',    'w',    'x',    'y',    'z'
    };

    int i=0;
    while(i<n) {
        char c=str[i];
        auto search = std::find(table.begin(), table.end(), c);
        if(search!=table.end()) {
            int dist = std::distance(search, table.begin());
            cout<<dist;     //prints out -0-1-2-3 instead of 0123, why?
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Working program is [here](https://www.ideone.com/6eLTUI)

Comment: Are you sure it prints `-` before the zero? It doesn't when I try it.

Comment: In you link you do have correct way of dist int dist = std::distance(table.begin(), search); but your code is different

Comment: @HariomSingh, that's because I changed it later.

Comment: It is really strange that std::distance has a signed return type. A distance by definition cannot be negative; A difference can be but not a distance. A better name would have been std::diff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the distance between those two iterators is negative; you have them in the wrong order.  The "lesser" iterator should be on the left, not the right.

You have: `std::distance(search, table.begin())`

You should have: `std::distance(table.begin(), search)`

Comment: Oh, never thought about that.  So the 'dash' apparently is the negative sign!  Thank you! :)  I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Correct.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela does it really print `-0-1-2-3` or `0-1-2-3` ?

Comment: I realize that from 2011 the distance is allowed to be negative, but it still bugs me. In fact it really pisses me off.

Comment: @Slava `std::abs()`. Or just fix your argument order.

Answer (score 3):

> why using std::distance is printing out a blank `-`

`-` character is the minus sign. It is used to represent negative numbers. So, `-` is printed because you print negative numbers. The distances are negative because the first argument is latter than the second one.

> how I could get rid of it?

If you calculate the distance from earlier position to the latter, the distance will be positive:

```
std::distance(table.begin(), search);
```

In this case you do know, but in case you don't know or care about the order and only want the absolute distance, you can get it using the function `std::abs`:

```
std::abs(std::distance(it1, it2));
```

---

PS. Passing latter iterator first is allowed only if the iterator is random access.

Comment: Note that for negative distances, not all containers work. Some (probably most) containers, like linked lists, will give undefined behavior if asked to calculate a negative distance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard function `std::distance` accepts a range of the kind `[start, target]`. So you need to write

```
auto dist = std::distance( table.begin(), search );
```

Or without using the function `std::distance` you can just write

```
auto dist = search - table.begin();
```

because the class template `std::vector` has random access iterators.

A few words about the program.

It is the case when it is better to use C strings instead of standard containers like `std::vector` and correspondingly to use standard C functions instead of C++ algorithms.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const char *table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string s;

    std::getline( std::cin, s );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        c = std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c );

        if ( const char *p = std::strchr( table, c ) )
        {
            std::cout << p - table << ' ';
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter

```
Umedh Singh Bundela
```

then the output will look like

```
20 12 4 3 7 18 8 13 6 7 1 20 13 3 4 11 0
```

Instead of the expression in the statement

```
std::cout << p - table << ' ';
```

you can use a call of `std::distance` if you want provided that you'll include header `<iterator>`

```
std::cout << std::distance( table, p ) << ' ';
```